# How can I add my custom App Part to the front page?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, development, sharepoint-addin, apps-development

I've created a custom app-part and published it to the catalog that I'd like to add as an app-part into a page. I've added the app to the site but it isn't showing when I try to insert it as an App Part, what am I missing?

Comment: a quick question, r u facing problem to find the app-part to add in the page. or after adding the app part, it is not responding or showing?

Comment: Answer was found here: http://jeffreypaarhuis.com/2013/03/22/how-to-create-an-app-part-in-sharepoint-2013/ - I had forgotten to add the client app part!